# mysql finding the sum of subgroup maximums

Tags: mysql, django, orm

If I have the following table in MySQL:

```
date        type amount
2017-12-01  3    2
2018-01-01  1    100
2018-02-01  1    50
2018-03-01  2    2000
2018-04-01  2    4000
2018-05-01  3    2
2018-06-01  3    1
```

...is there a way to find the sum of the `amount`s corresponding to the latest `date`s of each `type`? There are guaranteed to be no duplicate `date`s for any given `type`.

The answer I'd be looking to get from the data above could broken down like this:

- The latest `date` for `type` 1 is 2018-02-01, where the `amount` is 50;
- The latest `date` for `type` 2 is 2018-04-01, where the `amount` is 4000;
- The latest `date` for `type` 3 is 2018-06-01, where the `amount` is 1;
- 50 + 4000 + 1 = 4051

Is there a way to arrive directly at 4051 in a single query? This is for a Django project using MySQL if that makes a difference; I wasn't able to find an ORM-related solution either, so figured a raw SQL query might be a better place to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure for Django but in raw sql you could use a self join to pick latest row for each type based on latest date and then aggregate your results to get the sum of amounts for each type

```
select sum(a.amount)
from your_table a
left join your_table b on a.type = b.type
and a.date < b.date
where b.type is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddb8fb/3)

Or

```
select sum(a.amount)
from your_table a
join (
  select type, max(date) max_date
  from your_table
  group by type
) b on a.type = b.type
and a.date = b.max_date
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddb8fb/4)

Or by using a correlated subuery

```
select sum(a.amount)
from your_table a
where a.date =  (
  select max(date) 
  from your_table
  where type = a.type
)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddb8fb/5)

For Mysql 8 you can use window functions to get you desired result as

```
select sum(amount)
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by type order by date desc) as seq
      from your_table 
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/amRZ5GgCnHGGEtQkM4tmcW/0)

Comment: Those are all _incredibly_ helpful examples... thank you! I clearly need to become more familiar with the syntax, particularly for joins, as I'm still not sure _why_ your first example works in regards to the "b.type is null" part (though it clearly does get the right answer). Thanks again for such a thorough response.